# Using while loop to input value into Java process builder and getting the output

Tags: java, while-loop, processbuilder

Hi I am trying to execute an external program using java process builder.

The external program that I wish to execute prints out a string when giving it a fileName and press enter.

There are about a 100 files that I wish to do this task that are all in the same directory.

And to exit the program, I have to input 'quit' and press enter.

I was thinking of putting all the file names into a stack and do this process while the stack is not empty.

Ultimately my goal is to put the inputs and outputs into a csv file.

The code I currently have is as follows.

```
public void getNum(RoutingContext context) {
String command = context.getBodyAsJson().getString("command");
if (command.equals("ok")) {
  try {
    File folder = new File("/usr/local/bin/pic");
    ArrayList<String> toCsv = new ArrayList<>();
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    Stack<String> fileStack = new Stack<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++){
      fileStack.push(listOfFiles[i].toString());
    }
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", "./TestELANPRv2.2"});
    File dir = new File("/usr/local/elanpr-src");
    pb.directory(dir);
    Process start = pb.start();
    while(!fileStack.isEmpty()){
      String fileName = fileStack.pop();
      //input fileName to the process and get output
      //add fileName and output to toCsv
      
    }
    //exit program by typing in 'quit' and enter
    //write toCsv to CSV file

  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    log.info("Error.Running.CMD");
  }
}}
```

I've seen couple of solutions that does this with .getOutputStream and using writer to write into the outPutStream, but it is a bit unclear on how to execute it multiple times.

Hope my explanation was clear enough, and any sort of feedback would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You’re going to need to use threads I’m afraid. One to write and one to read - otherwise the process input/output buffers will fill up and your application will hang trying to write. So start a thread to read from the processes stdout then then in the main thread write to stdin.

Comment: @BoristheSpider yes. You may also need to deal with stderr in the same way.

Comment: Agree. Although if the program is not expected to write to stderr you can probably get away without. Often better safe than sorry though…

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback, I have set up an input and output buffers as you have suggested. However, I have succeeded in getting the first output, but the process just seems to wait instead of moving on to the next argument in the while loop. It would mean the world to me if you could take a look at my code and give me some feedback https://gist.github.com/3564cee3832dcf0311ba64e65b35bd48.git

Comment: Solved the problem, was stuck inside a while loop, because for some reason the program seems to think that there is something in the bufferedreader readline, even when it is empty. Gave it a break statement and seemed to work